# applescript inside python not working after monterey update

Tags: python, applescript, macos-monterey

I have the following code inside a python file:

```
applescript.run('''

        tell application "System Events"

            -- one second delay
            delay 1
            -- to press command+shift+g
            keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
            
            delay 2
            -- to enter file path
            keystroke "/Users/***/Documents/web_images/image_1.jpg"
            delay 1
            
            -- hit return twice
            keystroke return
            delay 1
            keystroke return

        end tell
        
''')
```

It was working great until I installed Monterey, now it's not working anymore. Anyone any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, ran a similar script from the script editor and had to give permission again for something, now it's working from inside python again as well.